# Using SuiteScript to extract metadata from Images in the file cabinet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm looking to build a particular solution for a client which needs to dynamically resize images stored in the Netsuite file cabinet.

Is there *any* way within suitescript/netsuite to grab the width and height of an image in the file cabinet?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

SuiteScript is basically javascript so if you can find any third party library that does this, you can add that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do this with SuiteScript, but you can do it via Web Services. If you do a "get" on each image file with PHP, you can then use the PHP getimagesize function to get the image dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Netsuite doesn't have anything native for this but a simple-ish solution would be to create a node app on AWS Lambda that accepts an image and resizes it.

You can't deploy a user event script on images so you'd be stuck with a scheduled script or a map reduce script. You can feed that with a list of images created since some date/time or you could set a User Note when the image has been resized and filter against that.

I've used the node package 'sharp' for this sort of thing and the speed and quality are good.